# How to merge two project in iphone

Tags: iphone

I am new to i phone programming.I want add one project into another project.In one project i have used root view controller and another project is view controller.In root view controller its displaying table view in starting after that if i click on the cell its will display the private document folder images,its working fine in root view controller project when i add this project to view controller i have made some changes in app delegate here after that when i run project first displaying view controller in that if click one button means its displaying table view but if click any cell in table view means its not working it.That root view controller project is https://github.com/kirbyt/KTPhotoBrowser

Here if click on that cell  its will all document images in thumbnails its not working can please help me what to do now.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have tried this but did not get success yet. I think it's not possible. The other way is to merge the methods of the other project yourself into the other project so that you can get the functionality of the other project.

Comment: Is there any other options

Comment: sorry buddy...if i will get the answer i will post here